# PUG Unexpected text

Tags: node.js, pug

I had to convert a jade file to pug format. I managed to correct some of the errors, but I block on this one:

```
> Error: C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\cours_nodejs\views\expressO1.pug:19:20
>     17|             $.get('/hello/', + $('[name=name]:checked').val(),
>     18| function(data) {
>   > 19|                    $('#message').html(data.message);
> ---------------------------^
>     20|                }, 'json' );
>     21|           }
> 
> unexpected text "$('#m"
>     at makeError (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\cours_nodejs\node_modules\pug-error\index.js:32:13)
>     at Lexer.error (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\cours_nodejs\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:59:15)
>     at Lexer.fail (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\cours_nodejs\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:1441:10)
>     at Lexer.advance (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\cours_nodejs\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:1501:15)
>     at Lexer.callLexerFunction (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\cours_nodejs\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:1456:23)
>     at Lexer.getTokens (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\cours_nodejs\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:1512:12)
>     at lex (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\cours_nodejs\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:12:42)
>     at Object.lex (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\cours_nodejs\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:99:27)
>     at Function.loadString [as string] (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\cours_nodejs\node_modules\pug-load\index.js:44:24)
>     at compileBody (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\cours_nodejs\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:86:18)
```

Despite my research, I failed to understand what was causing this error (nor to find a solution to solve it). Here is the code of the pug file:

```
doctype html
head
 title=theTitle
 body
   div Choisir unprenom :
   - for name intheNames
     label
      input(type="radio", name="name", value=name)
      spanPrenom : #{name}
     br
   div
      input(type="button", onclick="valid()",value="OK")
      #message
      script(src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js")
      script.
         function.valid() { 
            $.get('/hello/', + $('[name=name]:checked').val(),
function(data) {
                   $('#message').html(data.message);
               }, 'json' );
          }
```

Thank you for your advice !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to indent the  `function(data) {` line under the `$.get('/hello/', + $('[name=name]:checked').val(),`

i hope i helped

```html
doctype html
head
 title=theTitle
 body
   div Choisir unprenom :
   - for name intheNames
     label
      input(type="radio", name="name", value=name)
      spanPrenom : #{name}
     br
   div
      input(type="button", onclick="valid()",value="OK")
      #message
      script(src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js")
      script.
         function.valid() { 
            $.get('/hello/', + $('[name=name]:checked').val(),
               function(data) {
                   $('#message').html(data.message);
               }, 'json' );
          }
```

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for your answer. I tried to indent the function(data) but I get another error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token (16:4)"

Comment: `- for name intheNames`
there's something wrong with this line, maybe the dash

Comment: i think i figured it out, don't need the dash at the front of the line, and you have a typo in for syntax: `for name in theNames`
and indent right under the previous line `div Choisir unprenom :`

Comment: I try to remove the dash, but I get another error with "for name intheNames" : Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: change "intheNames" to "in theNames" if the variable what you want to send to pug is "theNames"
the right for syntax is "for name in theNames"